# Why should I not use TempData, Session, and ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

A peer was reviewing my code and told me the following about my code:

- Remove ViewBag & TempData usage.
- Avoid "Session" usage.

#### Code:

```
    public partial class LandingController : BaseController
    {
        public LandingController(IPPContext ppContext, IEmailHelper emailHelper, IProvideResources resourceProvider, IOldUrlMapper urlMapper)
        {
            _ppContext = ppContext;
            _resourceProvider = resourceProvider;
            _emailHelper = emailHelper;
            _urlMapper = urlMapper;
        }
...
 public virtual ActionResult Index(string siteName, string userName = null)
...

 [HttpPost]
 public virtual ActionResult Index(Login login, string RedirectUrl)
```

Why do we not use `ViewBag`, `TempData` or `Session`? What are the alternative ways to hold data between requests?

Comment: Your title should be what someone would search for if they had your issue.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person that reviewed your code? That person already knows all the answers.

Comment: Remove ViewBag, TempData, Session. So you dont want to store any data other than DB :). May be Application/ Cookie / Url will be the alternative

Comment: possible duplicate of [Still ok to use Session variables in ASP.NET mvc, or is there a better alternative for some things (like a cart)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744493/still-ok-to-use-session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc-or-is-there-a-better-alternati)

Comment: ViewBag and Tempdata should not be used because it goes against the pattern of MVC pass this data in the model, and pass the model into the view. Many developers do not like changing the model and use the viewbag and tempdata as a shortcut to pass the data in.

The reason to avoid storing items in the session is to do with performance, if the session object gets to big it slows things down. Store only what is absolutely necessary in the session, and keep it small. If your are running in proc your sessions are stored in memory and in a large system this will consume memory very quick.

Comment: Another alternative would be passing your model using a custom MVC model binder, which follows the principles of MVC. See here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx and here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx

Comment: @nvoigt Yeah... First I want to make sure that I am at the right line so I need your help guys... :)

Comment: Personally I see no problem in storing a temporary string/value in tempdata. eg you want the user to return to the same page with a message "Your data has been saved". On the other hand, its quite funny to see the presence of ViewBag, Session & TempData in the code you provided... Or the lack thereof

Comment: I think [@darin-dimitrov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) [stated it best](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346456/if-there-is-viewbag-for-viewdata-why-is-there-no-tempbag-for-tempdata#comment7428611_6346517) - *"I have no idea and quite honestly I don't care much about it. I never needed and used them anyways. For me `ViewData/ViewBag` are evil and their usage imply a poorly designed ASP.NET MVC application."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for avoiding session can be because concurrent ajax requests from same would be handled one after the other thereby slowing the performance.
http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this link may answer the question, it's always better to explain the main points from the link in the answer here. Links become useless if the link changes or site becomes unavailable. Can you expand on your answer please?